# Navbar div off centre by border

Tags: html, css, border, margin

I have a navbar:

HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navbar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    border-color: #B2B2B2;
    border-style: solid;
    -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
    -moz-border-radius: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
}
```

For some reason, the border makes it offcenter, there is always some space to the left of the div but not on the right. How do I fix this problem???

Comment: does margin: auto; help at all?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `width: 100%` from your CSS. The `div` is block-level, so will take up all available horizontal space. Adding an explicit 100% just introduces problems when you then give it `padding` or, in this case, `border`

Comment: Thanks! Perfect solution, i will bear this in mind with future divs! :D

Answer (score 0):

Add border-width and CSS3 box sizing to fix the issue.

```
border-width:2px;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ADwwP/1/